# ViewPager animation with slide imageview and textview fadein and fadeout

Tags: animation, android-viewpager

In Android, I have a viewPager, with views having ImageView & some other TextView items. I want to animate with slide the ImageView and fadein-fadeout of other textviews. How can I achieve this?

Cheers
Annada

Comment: Please be more specific...

Comment: I wanted an animation on viewpager, each page contains a background image and other textview fields. The animation required was slide/swipe the image, where the other textview items on the same page should be fadein & fadeout.

Comment: However I was doing some research on ViewPager.PageTransformer, and got the solution.  1. By default pageview amination is slides/swipe. 2. So just need to make separate layout, which required fadein/fadeout. 3. Get the fadein/fadeout layout in side transformPage(), and do the setAlpha() according to position.